# Display which radio button selected

Tags: vb.net, button, radio-button

I'm having some trouble displaying 3 radio buttons in 1 label, on which radio button is selected, so i have 3 radio buttons,

Radio button names:

```
Single
Season
Flex
```

so if radio button 1 selected displayed in lblReceiptAns.Text = "Option: " ,

```
Select Case True
  Case radSingle.Checked
    Pricez = CDbl(txtTickets.Text) * SINGLETICKETS
    TotalPricce = Pricez
  Case radSeason.Checked
    Pricez = CDbl(txtTickets.Text) * SEASONTICKCETS
    TotalPricce = Pricez
  Case radFlexPack.Checked
    Pricez = CDbl(txtTickets.Text) * FLEXPACK
    TotalPricce = Pricez
End Select

If txtVenue.Text = "STADIUM" Then
  lblReceiptAns.Visible = True
  lblReceiptAns.Text = "Option: " & 
Else
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would create a new module-level string variable - Say `RadioButtonSelected`, then set it's value in the `RadioButton_CheckChanged` module.

Then you simply have:

```
lblReceiptAns.Text = "Option: " & RadioButtonSelected
```